# Sending Mime Mail from Domino Agent: multiple instances of TO: field

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, mime-message

When creating a Mime mail message through LotusScript I observe that each recipient entered into the mimeHeader fields is showing up three times at the recipient's (external) mail client (doesn't happen if I open that mail through my Notes client).

Here's the relevant fragment of my test code:

```
    sn.Convertmime = False
    Set db = sn.Currentdatabase
    Set doc = db.Createdocument()
    Set nstr = sn.Createstream()
    Set mimeRoot = doc.Createmimeentity("body")
    Set mimeHeader = mimeRoot.Createheader("To")
    Call mimeHeader.setHeaderVal("some.recipient@mail.com")
    Set mimeHeader = mimeRoot.Createheader("CC")
    Call mimeHeader.setHeaderVal("other.recipient@mail.com")
    Set mimeHeader = mimeRoot.Createheader("Subject")
    Call mimeHeader.Addvaltext("Testmail MIME multipart (Part 1: set recipients in mimeHeader)", "utf-8")

    sMimeBoundary = LCase(doc.UniversalID)

    Set mimeRootChild = mimeRoot.createChildEntity
    Set mimeHeader = mimeRootChild.createHeader("Content-Type")
    Call mimeHeader.setHeaderVal("multipart/mixed; boundary='" + sMimeBoundary + "'")

    Set mimeEntity = mimeRootChild.createChildEntity
    Call nstr.Writetext("<div>Mail body, first line</div><br/>" &_
    {<div>###Second line with different <span style=color:red;>formatting</span>###</div>")
    Call mimeEntity.setContentFromText(nstr, "text/html;charset='utf-8'", ENC_NONE)
    Call nstr.close

    Call nstr.Truncate()
    Call doc.Send(False)
    sn.Convertmime = True
```

The resulting mail (e.g. in Outlook or Thunderbird etc.) is showing three independant instances of the "TO" and "CC" fields each one holding the single recipient's address. Excerpt from received mail's source code (taken from Thunderbird):

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
To: some.recipient@mail.com
CC: other.recipient@mail.com
To: some.recipient@mail.com
CC: other.recipient@mail.com
To: some.recipient@mail.com
CC: other.recipient@mail.com
Message-ID: <OF58C4AF46.9EDA9225-ONC125822D.0043D902-C125822D.0043E7C3@xxx.de>
From: Lothar Mueller <some.recipient@mail.com>
Date: Wed, 7 Feb 2018 13:21:04 +0100
X-MIMETrack: Itemize by NLNOTES.EXE on Lothar Mueller/xxx/DE(Release 9.0.1FP9|August
 15, 2017) at 07.02.2018 13:21:42,
    Serialize by Router on DomServer/xxx/DE at 07.02.2018 13:21:05,
    Serialize complete at 07.02.2018 13:21:05
MIME-Version: 1.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Sending the same mail to my Notes account and examining it there I see that it contains the following fields:

- AltSendTo
- InetSendTo
- SendTo
- AltCopyTo
- InetCopyTo
- CopyTo

Each instance of *SendTo / *CopyTo field contains the *same* MIME header content, e.g.

```
Effective Notes Value: "other.recipient@mail.com"
Original RFC822 Item Name: "CC"
Original RFC822 Item Delimiter: ": "
Original RFC822 Item Body: "other.recipient@mail.com
"
```

So in effect the Notes mail contains three identical instructions to create the TO and CC fields.

Question is: how can I stop Notes/Domino to do this? My preferred method would be through some kind of coding as opposed to some setting in the server config

EDIT: just tried the "old school" method of writing the recipients directly into the Notes fields as in `Call doc.replaceItemValue("SendTo", "some.recipient@mail.com")`. 
Result: no more multiplication of recipients, i.e. only one instance of TO and CC fields. Is this really the preferred way to go?

Comment: Yes, that really is the preferred way to go. Strictly speaking, To and Cc aren't MIME headers. They are old-fashioned RFC-822 headers. (I'm not sure if that fact has any bearing on why they are multiplied when you set them as MIME headers, but I do suspect that the Notes/Domino core code isn't expecting a MIME header to be redundant with the standard message addressing headers.)

Comment: Many thanks for your input. I'm not really an expert when it comes to Mime etc, so I had a look at what Designer help and other sources have in store. And the above code seemed to be the valid solution.